# Bash While Loop Counter Incrementing Incorrectly

Tags: bash, shell

There is a bash while loop with a counter, the first iteration is correct, but on the second iteration the counter increments by a random number, and from then on continues to increment as expected value of 1. Running Bash v4.2

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

```
COUNTER=1
while true
do 
    echo -e "$(date)\nCount $COUNTER "
    aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --region eu-west-2 --namespace example/test --metric-data file:///tmp/metrics.dat
    COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))
    sleep 60
done > /tmp/metrics.log 2>&1 &
```

Tail output for log

```
tail -f /tmp/metrics.log 

Fri 18 Jun 08:42:15 BST 2021
Count 1 
Fri 18 Jun 08:42:40 BST 2021
Count 28 
Fri 18 Jun 08:43:42 BST 2021
Count 29 
Fri 18 Jun 08:44:43 BST 2021
Count 30 
Fri 18 Jun 08:45:45 BST 2021
```

If the process is not redirected to the log file, then it works as expected. So the issue appears to be around this:

```
> /tmp/metrics.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: maybe the aws process is using the COUNTER variable too

Comment: There is only 25 seconds between the first counter output and the second. Can you confirm this is the output of the exact provided command ?  Maybe you're using concurrent runs of theses commands ?

Comment: BTW `COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+1))` = `let COUNTER++`

Comment: Can you have a run with the script except name all `COUNTER`s to `COUNTER_NEW_X` ?

Comment: Use `(( COUNTER++ ))`, no `$` inside the `((  ))`

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript` to get a debug log showing how and when the variable changes